# Azure Search like scheduling for Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, timer-trigger

Azure Search offers functionality to set up a Start DateTime and Interval (in mins) to schedule Indexer runs. Is there any way we can implement a similar configuration in Azure Function with Timer Trigger to start at a particular DateTime and then after at every interval?

Comment: Yes, you can setup the [cron expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations) based on your need.

Comment: You already have the answer in your question. Use Timer Trigger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Azure timer trigger function` cannot set `Start Time`. The timer trigger runs from the current time and executes the function according to the cycle specified by the [NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).

Solution:

Maybe you can use [Azure logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) to solve your problem, but in this solution, you need to use [Http trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp).

First, you need to use the [Recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence#add-the-recurrence-trigger), this timer can specify the time to start running, and then you can specify the time interval by changing the `Frequency`; then you need to use the [Function connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) to call your `Function`.

**Note:**

To be able to be called by Azure logic app, you need to use http trigger.

Please refer to my azure logic app:

[image]